# In in WPF controls, which ones are similar to `<div>` HTML tag?

Tags: html, wpf, controls, tags

I need to wrap a group of WPF controls to that I can toggle their visibility at the same time. How can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`StackPanel`, `DockPanel`, `WrapPanel` are mainly used for design, to align the controls in a specific way. Therefor i would use the `Grid`.

All of these can be used, but using a Panel just for hide and seek would make it lose its meaning.

Answer (score 5):

Use `StackPanel` or other kinds of panels depending on your need (`WrapPanel` if you need wrapping).

Answer (score 2):

Any of the panels - Grid, stackpanel, canvas, etc - in WPF can be Visible/Collapsed/Hidden. Just set the visibility of the object to Visibility.Hidden or Visibility.Collapsed. Notice the Name="" attribute...

```
<StackPanel Name="Test" Visibility="Visible">  
     ...  
</StackPanel>
```

On the code-behind, do a simple Name.Visibility conversion:

```
Test.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
Test.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
Test.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

It's also worth noting that most (if not all?) objects have Visibility. Buttons, menu items, etc, etc... Button Name="MyButton, Mybutton.Visibility =...

Edit: Link I posted wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the layout panels: `StackPanel`, `DockPanel`, `WrapPanel` or `Grid`.